# Bootstrapping a logistic regression in R, benefits?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, bootstrap

I am currently researching the bootstrap approach and its different versions/ uses and am trying to code and explain a more intricate example of bootstrapping. I have chosen to work on a logistic regression of the titanic data set already available in the R package COUNT. I have managed to find coefficients, plot the bootstrapped results, and found the confidence intervals (just the percentile ones), however, I don't know how to explain what is being seen that is so much more interesting than when I used the bootstrap on a simple linear regression and it all feels very repetitive with 5 different confidence intervals and plots. Any suggestions on how to make more interesting discoveries or how to explain why using the bootstrap are so useful for a logistic regression would be much appreciated.

here is my code so far:

```
library(COUNT)
data("titanic")
set.seed(111)
titanic$Survival<- titanic$survived == "yes"
logit_test <- function(data, indices){
  dt <- data[indices, ]
  fit <- glm(Survival ~ age+sex+factor(class), data=dt, family=binomial)
  return(coef(fit))
}
boot_strap <- boot(  
  data = titanic, 
  statistic = logit_test, 
  R = 1000)
boot_strap
plot(boot_strap, index = 1)
plot(boot_strap, index = 2)
plot(boot_strap, index = 3)
plot(boot_strap, index = 4)
plot(boot_strap, index = 5)
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_strap, type = "perc", index = 1)
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_strap, type =  "perc", index = 2)
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_strap, type =  "perc", index = 3)
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_strap, type =  "perc", index = 4)
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_strap, type = "perc", index = 5)
```

Comment: As a side note, bootstrap confidence intervals can be very inaccurate for odds ratios, especially with a very low or very high prevalence outcome.  So it's not clear why you need the bootstrap here.